# What is the best way to establish if the request comes from the Silverstripe CMS?

Tags: silverstripe

If you want to work out if a request comes from the CMS in the Silverstripe Framework - rather than the "front-end", then what is the best way to do so?

```
public function IsAdmin()
{
    return Controller::curr() instanceof LeftAndMain ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this ?

```
if (is_subclass_of(Controller::curr(), "LeftAndMain"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Another approach might be to see if it themes are "turned on"?